# Intersections of open cosets in a profinite group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be profinite groups and $\varphi\colon G \to H$ be a continuous homomorphism. It is true that $$\ker(\varphi) = \bigcap_{V \leq_o G} V$$ where $V$ runs trough the set of open subgroups of $G$. This implies, in turn, the equality: $$\bigcap_{V \leq_o G} (V - \ker(\varphi)) = \varnothing$$ where $V - \ker(\varphi)$ denotes their *set difference*. Now, $V - \ker(\varphi)$ is not necessarily closed in $G$. I'm interested in a proof or a counterexample to the following statement:

> Is it true that when $V$ runs trough the open subgroups of $G$ containing $\ker(\varphi)$ we have
> $$\bigcap_{V \leq_o G} \overline{V - \ker(\varphi)} = \varnothing\,?$$

Comment: It seems to be false if $[G:\ker(\varphi)] = \infty$, because then it has empty interior. Taking complements, and noticing that the interior of $V^c \cup \ker(\varphi)$ equals $V^c$, we should have $\bigcap_{V \leq_o G} \overline{V - \ker(\varphi)} = \ker(\varphi)$.