# Kernel of restriction to dense subgroup is again dense

Tags: general-topology, abelian-groups, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, profinite-groups

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological compact abelian groups, and let $A$ and $B$ be dense subgroups of $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Let $\varphi\colon X \to Y$ be a continuous homomorphism such that $\varphi(A) \subseteq B$, i.e., we have the following commutative diagram:

$$\begin{matrix}
A & \rightarrow & B\\
\downarrow & & \downarrow\\
X & \rightarrow & Y
\end{matrix}$$

> **Question.** If $\varphi_A\colon A \to B$ denotes the restriction of $\varphi\colon X \to Y$ to $A$, is $\ker(\varphi_A)$ a dense subgroup of $\ker(\varphi)$?

---

I'm specifically interested when $X$ and $Y$ are profinite (compact and totally disconnected). This is certainly true if $\ker(\varphi)$ is open in $X$, and I've tried to reduce the closed case to the open case by writing $\ker(\varphi) = \bigcap_{N \unlhd_o G} N$ as an intersection of the open normal subgroups containing it, but my argument breaks down in a [crucial part](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3779471/intersections-of-open-cosets-in-a-profinite-group).

Comment: I haven't thought about the profinite case, but in general it's not true: Let $X = Y = S^1$, $A = B = e^{i\mathbb{Z}}$, $\varphi(z) = z^n$ for $n \geqslant 2$. Then $\ker \varphi_A = \{1\}$ is closed, and $\ker \varphi$ contains $n$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true even for profinite groups. Let $X=(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\aleph_0}$, let $\varphi:X\to Y$ be the quotient by the subgroup of elements all of whose coordinates are the same (observe $\ker\varphi$ has only two elements), and let $A$ be the dense subgroup of $X$ of elements almost all of whose coordinates are zero. Then $A$ is dense, but its intersection with $\ker \varphi$ is trivial.